# How to get matrix $A$ from $A^\top A=B$ with given symmetric matrix $b$?

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, matrix-equations

Given a symmetric matrix $B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

How many coefficients of  $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ can you obtain from the following equation?
$$A^\top A=B$$

I think this problem is under determined? Isn't it? Sure $B$ must be symmetric. Thus  only $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ complex equations remain for $n\times n$ coefficients.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using capital letters for matrices. Else $a^\top a=b$ looks like $a$ is a (column) vector and $b$ is a scalar.

Comment: @Leo Done!Is it OK now? Is $A^\top A$ clear? Means transposed matrix $A$ multiplied with matrix $A$.

Comment: is $A$ unique? if $A$ is a solution isn't $AQ,$ for any orthogonal matrix $Q$ is also a solution?

Comment: @abel seems to be so.

Comment: i should have said if $A$ is a solution so is $QA$ for any orthogonal matrix $Q.$ not $AQ$ as i said in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not completely sure about complex numbers, but... If $A^\top A=B$ then, $B$ is symmetric positive semi-definite. So you can take the eigenvalue/vector decomposition of $B$, such that $B=U\Lambda U^\top$.
Then $A=(U\Lambda^{1/2})^\top$.

Comment: Nothing changes in $\mathbb{C}$, because the eigenvalues of $B$ are all real and nonnegative, so their square roots are real and nonnegative.

Comment: what about uniqueness?

Comment: @abel That means that $A=U \left(\Lambda^{1/2}\right)^\top$ with arbitrary $U\in \text U(n)$ is the solution?

Comment: you are using the same letter $U$ in two different ways. the solution is not unique.

Answer (score 1):

From matrix analysis, if $B$  is complex-symmetric, there is a unitary matrix $U$ such that $B=UDU^{T}$ where the columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of $BB^{*} = B \bar{B}$ and $D$ is diagonal and the entries are the positive square roots of the corresponding eigenvalues. Now, if the columns of $U$  are real, then $U$ is orthogonal and so $B$ is orthogonally diagonalisable, and what I wrote then follows. So, if the eigenvectors of $B \bar{B}$  are real, then the eigenvalues of $B$ are real. The last part here may not be of any use but I think the former is.

Answer (score 1):

The davcha and Ian posts are false when $\mathbb{C}$ is the underlying field. Of course, the OP gave a green chevron to davcha, although his solution is valid only on R....

1. Any complex matrix is similar to a symmetric matrix. Then a symmetric matrix may be non-diagonalizable !
2. The real case is treated in:    [General Cholesky-like decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962016/general-cholesky-like-decomposition)   . cf. my post (which has not been read) where all solutions are determined.
3. If $A$ is a complex matrix , then the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ have no special property and $B$ is certainly not symmetric positive semi-definite.
4. About the OP's question. Using the Autolatry's post, we can find particular solutions. Indeed there is a SVD of $B$ in the form $B=UDU^T$ (beware $U^T\not= U^{-1}$). Let $\Delta$ be one of the square roots of $D$. Then the $A=\Delta U^T$ are particular solutions. Yet, there are many other solutions. For example, for a generic symmetric $B$, if $n=3$ (resp $n=4$) then the degree of freedom of the solutions is $3$ (resp. $6$).