# How to solve $C = X^\top C X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

All matrices are $n \times n$. $C$ is real symmetric positive definite.

How to solve $C = X^\top C X$ for $X$?

I am interested in characterizing both the set of *real* matrices satisfying the equation and the (possibly larger) set of complex solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Choleski, $C=B^TB=X^TB^TBX=Y^TY$ with $Y=BX$. Then it remains to solve $B^TB=Y^TY$. Cf. my posts, for the real case, in [General Cholesky-like decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962016/general-cholesky-like-decomposition) and, for the complex case, in [How to get matrix $A$ from $A^\top A=B$ with given symmetric matrix $b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063441/how-to-get-matrix-a-from-a-top-a-b-with-given-symmetric-matrix-b/1067095#1067095)