# Cholesky-like decomposition of indefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Given a trace-$0$ matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with an equal number of positive and negative eigenvalues, I want to find matrix $L$ such that $L^T L = W$. Can one do such a factorisation?Right now I am able to factorise it as $$D=A\otimes A^{T}-C\otimes C^{T}$$
The main goal is to prove that the matrix has got equal number of positive and negative Eigen values.

Comment: Let $A^tA$ have eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $(Av)^tAv=v^tA^tAv=v^t\lambda v=\lambda v^tv$, but $(Av)^tAv$ is nonnegative and $v^tv$ is positive so $\lambda\ge0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This means such a decomposition is not possible for a matrix with equal number of positive and negative Eigen values. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It means it's not possible for such a matrix to have any negative eigenvalues at all.

Comment: If I got W=AA^T-BB^T, Is it possible to prove that W has got equal number of positive and negative eigen values

Comment: I don't know. Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Have you tried letting $A$ and $B$ be different multiples of the identity?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I didn’t understand that. Can you explain? W is a matrix with equal number of positive and negative eigenvalues. That’s already proved numerically. W can be written as AA^T-BB^T. That is already proved. What needs to be proved is that from this structure, any analytical proof that it has got equal number of positive and negative eigen values

Comment: @Jasmine [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801417/339790) may help you.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo what please

Comment: @Jasmine Why don't you start with $D = \mbox{diag}(1,-1)$ and try to find a square root of $D$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Did you mean just a 2 X 2 diagonal  matrix with 1 and -1 in the diagonal?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/962016/339790)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128400/discussion-between-jasmine-and-rodrigo-de-azevedo).

Comment: If $A=2I$, and $B=I$, then $AA^t-BB^t$ has a positive eigenvalue, and no negative eigenvalues. If $A=I$, and $B=2I$, then $AA^t-BB^t$ has a negative eigenvalue, and no positive eigenvalues. So, being of the form $AA^t-BB^t$ tells you nothing about the number of positive or the number of negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Any thoughts about my answer, Jasmine?

Comment: Not polite to ask a question and then fail to engage with the user who provides an answer, jasmine.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Really sorry that I was busy. The reasoning you have said is awesome.

Comment: You have the option, Jasmine, of "accepting" the answer, by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Sure Gerry......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a matrix $W$ has any negative eigenvalues at all, then it can't be written as $L^tL$ (for $L$ real). For let $v$ be an eigenvector of $W$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $v^tv>0$, and $$\lambda v^tv=v^tWv=v^tL^tLv=(Lv)^t(Lv)\ge0$$ so $\lambda\ge0$.

Comment: What if $L$ is complex-valued and one uses non-Hermitian transposition?

Comment: @Rodrigo, then you can have negative eigenvalues, e.g., $L=\pmatrix{i&0\cr0&i}$, $W=L^tL=\pmatrix{-1&0\cr0&-1}$. But who would ever want to use non-Hermitian transposition on a matrix with nonreal entries?

Comment: No one, I assume.  My somewhat cheeky comment's motivation was as follows. Given an indefinite real and symmetric matrix $A$, one can find matrix $R$ such that $R^\top R = A$, though not a real $R$. Hence, it would be wise to mention to which set $R$ must belong.

Comment: OK, @Rodrigo, you win. I've made an edit.